# Calculate Date Interval - on android for SDK lower 24

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to calculate date interval with a simple way, without any date formatter. I thought of using android library function `DateInterval` but that requires min API 24, while I want to go with lower API. Most SO solutions using dateFormatter which I do not want or need. What is a simplistic way of finding interval between two dates?

Code:

```
thread { 
               val prevDate = Date()
               sleep(3000)
               val cDate = Date()
               val intervalDate = DateInterval(prevDate.time, cDate.time) // requis API24. What is alternative?

               Log.d("", interval...) 

        }
```